# Android Studio still giving me the warning about anti-virus program impacting my build performance besides adding exceptions

Tags: android, android-studio

I still get the warning about my anti-virus program impacting my build performance, even though I have added the below exceptions in Avast:

```
C:\Androidstudioprojectss\*
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\*
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio2\*
C:\Program Files\Java\*
C:\Sdk5-2019\*
C:\Users\[my username]\.android\*
C:\Users\[my username]\.gradle\*
C:\Users\[my username]\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2021.1\*
C:\Users\[my username]\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\*
```

I'm using Android Studio Bumblebee (2021.1.1). Pleases advise what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Add it in your Windows Defender(Windows Security) as well.

Add these folders as exclusion.

ALso if you have an above average machine the build time difference is not that significant

Comment: I think once you install another anti-virus program, Windows Defender no longer becomes your default anti-virus program so I can't add exception in both Windows Defender and Avast.

Comment: Yeah i understand but the warning stems from your WIndows Security

Comment: After going to Google to check how to add the exclusion, I went to the program but there is no option to add exclusions. Please assist?

Comment: Search for Windows Security > Virus and Threat Protection > Manage Settings > Exclusions > Add or Remove Exclusions

Comment: When I go to Virus & Threat Protection, it says Avast Antivirus is turned on.

Comment: Yeah it will not allow .. Turn Avast off for a while change settings turn it on

Answer (score -2):

Turn off all anti-virus program

And try again